# Button Feedback like Spotify

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I want to have a button feedback like Spotify form my Buttons. That means when I click the button the button should be a bit smaller and it should get a light gray ton. That's easy I know but I don't know how to make that with an animation.
Thats the Sample-Button:`<Button id="SpotifyButton"/>`

[image]

I'm looking forward to getting a answer! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hole answer based on the answer from **Android Geek**.

> view_press.xml (in anim res folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true" android:fillBefore="true">
    <scale
        android:duration="100"
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:pivotX="70%"
        android:pivotY="70%"
        android:toXScale="0.95"
        android:toYScale="0.95" >
    </scale>
</set>
```

> view_release.xml (in anim res folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true" android:fillBefore="true">
    <scale
        android:duration="100"
        android:fromXScale="0.95"
        android:fromYScale="0.95"
        android:pivotX="70%"
        android:pivotY="70%"
        android:toXScale="1"
        android:toYScale="1">
    </scale>
</set>
```

> CustomView

```
    public class SpotifyButton extends AppCompatTextView {


    int backgroundColor = ((ColorDrawable) getBackground()).getColor();
    GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = getBackgroundShape(backgroundColor);
    ValueAnimator defaultAnimator = getDefaultBackgroundAnimator(this);

    public SpotifyButton (Context context) {
        super(context);
        setOnTouchListener();
        setBackground(gradientDrawable);
    }

    public SpotifyButton (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setOnTouchListener();
        setBackground(gradientDrawable);
    }

    public SpotifyButton (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setOnTouchListener();
        setBackground(gradientDrawable);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        super.performClick();
        return true;
    }

    public static int manipulateColor(int color, float factor) {
        int a = Color.alpha(color);
        int r = Math.round(Color.red(color) * factor);
        int g = Math.round(Color.green(color) * factor);
        int b = Math.round(Color.blue(color) * factor);
        return Color.argb(a,
                Math.min(r, 255),
                Math.min(g, 255),
                Math.min(b, 255));
    }

    public ValueAnimator getDefaultBackgroundAnimator(final View view) {
        final float[] from = new float[3],
                to = new float[3];

        Color.colorToHSV(backgroundColor, from);
        Color.colorToHSV(manipulateColor(backgroundColor, 0.7f), to);

        ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
        anim.setDuration(200);

        final float[] hsv = new float[3];
        anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                // Transition along each axis of HSV (hue, saturation, value)
                hsv[0] = from[0] + (to[0] - from[0]) * animation.getAnimatedFraction();
                hsv[1] = from[1] + (to[1] - from[1]) * animation.getAnimatedFraction();
                hsv[2] = from[2] + (to[2] - from[2]) * animation.getAnimatedFraction();
                gradientDrawable.setColor(Color.HSVToColor(hsv));
                view.setBackground(gradientDrawable);
            }
        });
        return anim;
    }

    public GradientDrawable getBackgroundShape(int color) {
        GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable();
        gradientDrawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
        gradientDrawable.setCornerRadius(100);
        gradientDrawable.setColor(color);
        return gradientDrawable;
    }

    public void setOnTouchListener() {
        this.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        Animation onclick_effect_press = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.ui_view_feedback_press);
                        defaultAnimator.start();
                        v.startAnimation(onclick_effect_press);
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        Animation onclick_effect_release = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.ui_view_feedback_release);
                        defaultAnimator.reverse();
                        v.startAnimation(onclick_effect_release);
                        if (isMotionEventInsideView(v, event)) {
                            performClick();
                        }
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

        });
    }

    private boolean isMotionEventInsideView(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        Rect viewRect = new Rect(
                view.getLeft(),
                view.getTop(),
                view.getRight(),
                view.getBottom()
        );

        return viewRect.contains(
                view.getLeft() + (int) event.getX(),
                view.getTop() + (int) event.getY()
        );
    }
}
```

> Resault

[image]

Happy coding!!

Answer (score 1):

> XML file

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_done"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_rect"
        android:paddingStart="60dp"
        android:paddingEnd="60dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Done"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

set background to your layout of button. here background is `bg_rect`

> drawable -- bg_rect is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>
            <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#5DA19C"/>
            <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
        </shape>

    </item>
</ripple>
```

change `solid android:color` according to your need.

Create `anim` directory in `res` file then add animation file in `anim` folder:

> Animation file -- onclick_effect.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <scale
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromXScale="0.9"
        android:fromYScale="0.9"
        android:pivotX="70%"
        android:pivotY="70%"
        android:toXScale="1"
        android:toYScale="1" >
    </scale>
</set>
```

Add click on button in java class:

```
llDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Animation onclick_effect = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.onclick_effect);
                llDone.startAnimation(onclick_effect);
            }
        });
```

Change color,animation time according to your need.

I hope its work for you.